# GNU makefile rules and dependencies

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I've been doing a lot of reading on how to write makefiles to build an application on Linux but I'm massively confused about the many different ways to apparently achieve the same goal.

This is what I have come up with so far to build an archive.

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

CXX = g++
DEBUG = -g
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic #-Wextra
CPPFLAGS =  -I. \
            -I./include

SOURCES =   foo1.cpp \
            foo2.cpp \
            foo3.cpp

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

The following rule successfully compiles each source file into an object file and then creates an archive:

```
libfoo.a: $(OBJECTS)
    ar rvcs $@ $(OBJECTS)

%.o: src/%.cpp ./include/%.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

This also does the same thing:

```
libfoo.a: $(OBJECTS)
    ar rvcs $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS) : %.o:src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

However, this fails with an error that there is no rule to make target 'foo1.o:%.h

```
libfoo.a: $(OBJECTS)
    ar rvcs $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS) : %.o:src/%.cpp %.o:%.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Can someone please explain why it doesn't work and which approach is best?

The first option lists the header files as dependencies but the second option doesn't. That is my motivation for the third option.

How do I list the headers as dependencies using options 2 or 3?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're using in try #2 and try #3 is [static pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) and the syntax looks like this:

```
<targets...> : <target-pattern> : <prerequisites...>
```

There can only be two colons, not three.  You should write your try #3 above as:

```
$(OBJECTS) : %.o : src/%.cpp %.h
        $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Note one critical thing: this rule will FAIL if you ever create any `.cpp` file which does *not* have an associated `.h` file.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Thanks. So that is saying the objects depend on %.o substituted with both .cpp and .h?

Comment: Which is the best approach?

Comment: The manual describes a static pattern rule... if you don't get it please ask a specific question about what's there that's confusing.  Basically it says "for each target listed in `<targets...>` create an explicit rule with the prerequisites that match the prereq patterns, where `%` is constructed from the match of the target".  It's easier to understand (IMO) in the manual.

Comment: I have no strong opinions on which is better.  I'm a traditionalist and tend to prefer normal pattern rules, but others think static pattern rules are better because they're more efficient (they create explicit rules, so make doesn't have to do pattern matching).  Both have uses; they can even both be used together (the pattern rule matches most things, but a static pattern rule to match some specific objects that need a different recipe).

Comment: Thanks for your help @MadScientist. I got side-tracked, hence the delay.